# NodeJs/Express Request Blocked By SetTimeout?

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

In the example below I've introduced an artificial delay of 10 seconds before the response is returned.

But if I open the page in two separate tabs in parallel, the 2nd request is blocked and does not start processing until the 1st request completes.  In other words the 2nd 'entering method' will not be displayed until after the 1st request fully completes (after 10 seconds).

Why is the 2nd request blocked?  I thought NodeJs was NOT supposed to block when async code is running.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    console.log('entering method');

    setTimeout(() => {
        res.send('hello world');
    }, 10000);
});
```

Comment: It's not "blocked", it's just that you are not sending anything. Put a `console.log("hello")` on the next line right after the `setTimeout()` to see that fire first.

Comment: You're right... as far as I can tell it looks like Chrome is waiting for the 1st request to complete before it sends the 2nd request, so it's not really Node related at all I guess

Comment: The problem isn't your code or Node.js -- it's how you set up your test.

You wrongly assumed that your browser would make 2 concurrent requests, which is not happening. Different browsers have different behaviors, but typically browsers limit to a very low number the maximum amount of simultaneous connections to a single origin. The HTTP spec gives a suggest maximum. I was actually quite surprised to see Chrome only opening 1 single connection to localhost, as I know Chrome opens 6 to other origins -- just learned something new!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many browsers limit the number of concurrent requests to the same server. This is a browser limitation, not a Node.js one.

Try using `curl` and you will see that the requests aren't blocked.

```
curl http://localhost:{port} &
curl http://localhost:{port} &
```

Or using apache benchmark:

```
ab -n 10 -c 2 http://localhost:{port}
```